# Javascript .dropdown-toggle() bootstrap function isn't closing after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My javascript .dropdown-toggle() bootstrap function isn't closing after it has dropped down and I click it again.

I've checked all the other questions on SO (there are a lot), but nothing works.

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});  
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) {
        echo "<div class=\"bs-e\">";
        echo "<div class=\"dropdown\">";
        echo        "<a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\">Options <b class=\"c\"></b></a>";
        echo        "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
        echo            "<li><a href=\"pa.php\">P A</a></li>";
        echo            "<li><a href=\"aED.php\">A T</a></li>";
        echo            "<li><a href=\"p_a_d.php\">D D</a></li>";
        echo            "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";
        echo            "<li><a href=\"logOut.php\">L O</a></li>";
        echo        "</ul>";
        echo    "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<button value=\"L O\" onclick=\"window.location='lO.php'\" class=\"submit\" style=\"margin-left:420px;margin-bottom:10px;\">Log Out </button>";
    }
?>
```

I want it to go back to its original state when I click the button a second time.

Comment: Setup a JSFiddle as an example or give us the html... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I updated it so it shows the php.

Comment: Is this a bad question?  How can I rephrase it to be more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adapted your HTML to more closely resemble what the Bootstrap docs use. I've added the attribute `role="menu"` to your `<ul>` (this isn't what fixed it but you should still include it) and also added the attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the `<a>` that triggered the dropdown. Without this the Bootstrap JS didn't quite know what to do with the dropdown. Here is a working jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/djrp5/

And here's the actual code

```
<div class="bs-e">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Options <b class="c"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="pa.php">P A</a></li>
                <li><a href="aED.php">A T</a></li>
                <li><a href="p_a_d.php">D D</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="logOut.php">L O</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'll admit that the actual documentation does not make this clear, however if you check the examples, specifically [this one](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/#), you'll see some toggle-able dropdowns there.